# Hive unable to read decimal value from hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

My hive version is 0.13.

I have a file that contain **decimal value** and few other data types.  This file is obtained after performing some Pig transformations. I created a Hive table on top of this HDFS file.  When I try to do a `select * from table_name`, I find that the decimal values in the file are truncated into integer values.  What could be the reason for this?

Below is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE FSTUDENT(
    load_dte string COMMENT 'DATE/TIME OF FILE CREATION',
    xyz DECIMAL,
    student_id int
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://clsuter1/tmp/neethu/part-m-00000';
```

The output for `select * from table_name` gives the decimal value for 1387.00000 as 1387.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Neethu: Altering table would not make any difference unless it is an external table.

As @K S Nidhin mentioned, As of Hive 0.13 users can specify scale and precision when creating tables with the DECIMAL datatype using a DECIMAL(precision, scale) syntax.  If scale is not specified, it defaults to 0 (no fractional digits). If no precision is specified, it defaults to 10. You can find the same in [hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-decimal)

try dropping the table `FSTUDENT` and recreate the table with DECIMAL(precision, scale). Somthing like

```
CREATE TABLE FSTUDENT(
    load_dte STRING,
    xyz DECIMAL(10,5), -- in your case
    student_id INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

or
truncate the table/ insert overwrite the data in to the table after altering the column datatype. Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes DECIMAL(10,5) works fine. Hive only displays for the values after decimal only if they are no zero's. In my case I had all of them as zero.So got into this confusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you haven't mentioned the precision.

```
DECIMAL with out precision will Defaults to decimal(10,0).
```

So you have to add precision to get the required value.

Comment: `hive -e "alter table FSTUDENT change xyz xyz DECIMAL(10,8)"`
Still i get 1387 .